# How to package the killbill hello-world plugin

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, killbill

I'm a ruby beginner trying to package a ruby gem from killbill. I tried debugging the problem but no luck.

When running `rake killbill:package` an exception is thrown:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `pos' for 
<Pathname:/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/cache/i18n-0.7.0.gem>:Pathname
```

The plugin is available here: https://github.com/killbill/killbill-hello-world-ruby-plugin

I followed the README to build the package and I'm stuck on the last step.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, care to set that as answer and I'll mark as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRuby 1.7.19 incompatibility (probably related to updated RubyGems), try downgrading JRuby (e.g. 1.7.16 should work fine) for the time being ... or look for a possible [resolution of the issue](https://github.com/killbill/killbill-plugin-framework-ruby/issues/21)